# Objective C class along with view based application-Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm new to iphone development.I have practiced some view based application programs and console applications.I'm developing a protocol which will be in .h and .m format.
My goal is that if a ok button is pressed then the retrieval of data has to be made from the other end device. So in the mean time it should display "Processing the request!!" message to the user.The message retrieval codes has to be implemented in objective C class(as .m and .h files). I created a button and a TextView in view based application and tried to include the classes of .m and .h along with it.I'm getting error as "Cocoa/Cocoa.h No such file or directory"..
I have the following frameworks 
1.UIKit.framework 2.Foundation.framework 3.CoreGraphics.framework

When I was working only in console application Foundation.framework is the only framework I had.

Is there any other framework or modification neeeded to run the console application(Objective C Class) along with the View based application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` (Mac) you need to do `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` on iOS.